# C++ user input twice before specified response

Tags: c++, controls, console-application

I am making a whack-a-mole game for my class but I am stuck on the basic controls. I setup a basic board, using an array with a border using ascii symbols, with O representing the holes and X the hammer. When I go to move the hammer, lets say to the right, I have to press it twice for the hammer to move and I don't know why. It has to go through the whole loop 2 times before moving the hammer the right way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
bool gamerunning = true;
const int num = 20; //width
const int num2 = 40; //height
int x, y, score, perx, pery;
int hole1x, hole1y;
int hole2x, hole2y;
int hole3x, hole3y;
int hole4x, hole4y;

void setup(){
     x= 5;
     y=5;
     hole1x = 15;
     hole1y = 5;
     hole2x = 15;
     hole2y = 10;
     hole3x = 25;
     hole3y = 5;
     hole4x = 25;
     hole4y = 10;
     score = 0;
     perx = 15;
     pery = 6;
}

 //creating board
 void draw(){
     system("cls");

     int i,j;
     char Layout[num][num2];


for (i=0;i<num;i++){
    for (j=0;j<num2;j++){

        //boarder for play area
        if (i==0 && j==0) //Top Left
            Layout [i][j] = 201;
        else if( i==0 && j==num2-1) //top right
            Layout [i][j] = 187;
        else if(i==num-1 && j==0) //bottom left
            Layout [i][j] = 200;
        else if(i ==num-1 && j==num2-1) //bottom right
            Layout [i][j] = 188;
        else if (i==0 || i==num - 1) 
            Layout[i][j]=205;
        else if(j==0 || j==num2-1)
            Layout [i][j] = 186;
        else
            Layout[i][j]=' ';                       


        //holes
        if(i == hole1y && j == hole1x)
            Layout[i][j]= 'O';
        if(i == hole2y && j == hole2x)
            Layout[i][j]= 'O';
        if(i == hole3y && j == hole3x)
            Layout[i][j]= 'O';
        if(i == hole4y && j == hole4x)
            Layout[i][j]= 'O';

        //character
        if(i == pery && j == perx)
            Layout[i][j]= 'X';


        cout << Layout[i][j];
    }

    cout << endl;
  }
}


void input(){

     if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)){
          if(perx<=15)
               perx +=10;
     }
     if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)){
         if(perx>=25)
               perx -=10;
     }
     if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)){
         if(pery<=10)
               pery +=5;
     }
     if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)){
         if(pery>=10)
               pery -=5;
     }
     if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)){
         gamerunning = false;
     }

}

void logic(){

}


int main(){

     setup();
     while(gamerunning == true){

         draw();
         input();
         logic();
         system("pause>nul");
     }

     system("cls");
     cout << "GAME OVER" << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please investigate your warning list.

Comment: I'm using code::blocks and its not giving me any warnings or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

```
while(gamerunning == true)
{
    draw();
    input();
    system("pause>nul");
    logic();
}
```

You first draw your game board then you get the input, drawing will not happen until the next time loop execution, so your drawing will not update.

You need to put first `draw` call outside the loop (for initial drawing) then inside the loop call `draw` after `input`. like this :

```
draw();
while(gamerunning == true)
{
    input();
    draw();
    system("pause>nul");
    logic();
}
```